Creating a DC low voltage amp with a gain of 2
I am working on a mic project and im working with the PCM2912A from TI. The micbias of this audiocodec is 0.75v but the mic im planning to use (JLI-2555BXZ3-GP) is rated for 1-10v and their example circuit uses 1.5v. How would i go about increasing such a low voltage for the mic?

Please add a link to the datasheet of PCM2912A. Avoidance of search processes saves energy, electrical and mental.

Read 0.75 × Vcc, that is about 2.4 V with Vcc = 3.3 V.

This uses USB power, i don't know if the Vcc is stable enough to combine with the micbias for microphone use

@Sweeid - The MIC bias voltage is derived from the internal, regulated 3.3V rail. More importantly, do you know that the microphone you selected is just a capsule and has no internal JFET buffer?

Please expand your answer
